# Python regex to get n characters before and after a keyword in a line of text

Tags: python, regex, string, file, findall

I'm trying to parse trough a file and search for a keyword in a list of strings. I need to return the 'n' characters before and after each occurrence. I have it working without regex but it's not very efficient. Any idea how to do the same with regex and findall? Lookup is a list of strings. This is what I have without regex:

```
with open(file, 'r') as temp:
    for num, line in enumerate(temp, 1):
        for string in lookup:
            if string in line:

                # Split the line in 2 substrings
                tmp1 = line.split(string)[0]
                tmp2 = line.split(string)[1]

                # Truncate only 'n' characters before and after the keyword
                tmp = tmp1[-n:] + string + tmp2[:n]

                # Do something here...
```

This is the start with regex:

```
with open(file, 'r') as temp:
    for num, line in enumerate(temp, 1):
        for string in lookup:
            # Regex search with Ignorecase
            searchObj = re.findall(string, line, re.M | re.I)

            if searchObj:
                print "search --> : ", searchObj

                # Loop trough searchObj and get n characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. Below is the code if anyone needs it:

```
with open(file, 'r') as temp:
    for num, line in enumerate(temp, 1):
        for string in lookup:

            # Regex
            searchObj = re.finditer(string, line, re.M | re.I)

            if searchObj:
                for match in searchObj:

                    # Find the start index of the keyword
                    start = match.span()[0]

                    # Find the end index of the keyword
                    end = match.span()[1]

                    # Truncate line to get only 'n' characters before and after the keyword
                    tmp = line[start-n:end+n] + '\n'            
                    print tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
start([group])
end([group])
   Return the indices of the start and end of the substring matched by 
   group; group defaults to zero (meaning the whole matched substring). 
   Return -1 if group exists but did not contribute to the match. For a 
   match object m, and a group g that did contribute to the match, the 
   substring matched by group g (equivalent to m.group(g)) is


    m.string[m.start(g):m.end(g)]

    Note that m.start(group) will equal m.end(group) if group matched a 
    null string. For example, after m = re.search('b(c?)', 'cba'), 
    m.start(0) is 1, m.end(0) is 2, m.start(1) and m.end(1) are both    
    2, and m.start(2) raises an IndexError exception.
```

Using `re.finditer` you can generate an iterator of `MatchObject` and then use these attributes to get the start and end of your substrings.